# why is the balance after depositing is = None?

Tags: python

I created this simple withdrawal and deposit machine and used a class method for depositing but there seems to be something wrong with it as I expected the return value of the deposit method to be = 20,500 but instead its = None , so what it is the problem here ? and are there any mistakes in my code ?

```
print("Hello !!! Welcome to Deposit & Withdrawal Machine")

class Account:
    withDrawalAmount = 0 
    depositAmnt = 0 
        
    def __init__(self, ID=0, balance=100, annual_interest_rate=0):
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__balance = balance
        self.__annual_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate

    #setters
    def setId(self, ID):
         self.__ID = ID

    def setBal(self, Bal):
         self.__balance = Bal

    def setAnnualInterestRate(self, annualIntrstRate):
         self.__annual_interest_rate = annualIntrstRate

    #getters
    def getId(self):
        return self.__ID

    def getBal(self):
        return self.__balance

    def getAnnualIntrstRate(self):
        return self.__annual_interest_rate

    #special getters 
    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        self.annual_rate = self.__annual_interest_rate / 100
        self.monthly_rate = self.annual_rate / 12
        return self.monthly_rate

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.__balance * self.monthly_rate

    #other methods

    def withdraw(self, withDrawalAmount):
        if self.__balance >= self.withDrawalAmount:
            self.__balance = self.__balance - self.withDrawalAmount 
            return self.__balance

    def deposit(self, depositAmnt ):
        if self.depositAmnt >=  1 :
            self.__balance = self.__balance + self.depositAmnt
            return self.__balance

client001 = Account(1122, 20000, 4.5)

print("Your Balance After withdrawal is : ", client001.withdraw(2500))
print("Your Balance After deposit is : ", client001.deposit(3000))
print("Your Account ID is : ", client001.getId())
print("Your Current Balance is : ", client001.getBal())
print("Your Monthly Intrst Rate is : ", client001.getMonthlyInterestRate())
print("Your Monthly intrst is : ", client001.getMonthlyInterest())
```

Comment: FYI [Python is not Java](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)

Comment: There isn't even any good reason for those class attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John already mentioned, to rectify this you need to use the variable `depositAmnt` in your if statement.

```
    def deposit (self , depositAmnt ):
        if depositAmnt >=  1 :
            self.__balance = self.__balance + depositAmnt
            return self.__balance
```

right now, the attributes of your class -`withDrawalAmount` and `depositAmnt` don't have any usage (since you are inputting them as an argument in your function `deposit` and `withdraw`.

You should also change the `withdraw` function as:

```
    def withdraw (self , withDrawalAmount):
        if self.__balance >= withDrawalAmount:
            self.__balance = self.__balance - withDrawalAmount 
            return self.__balance
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def deposit (self , depositAmnt ):
    if self.depositAmnt >=  1 :
        self.__balance = self.__balance + self.depositAmnt
        return self.__balance
```

The amount being deposited is `depositAmnt`, not `self.depositAmnt`.

So the `if` condition is false, therefore the function does not return anything, therefore it returns `None` by default.

Comment: It's also generally un-Pythonic to have a setter like this return a value at all.